# How to validate crontab scheduling values in bash

Tags: regex, bash, cron

I am writing a bash script that accepts the same scheduling values as the crontab does (day of the week, month, etc).

So far my script is able to accept an asterisk (`*`) for every value, or an integer for specific values. However my script also needs to support ranges (`-`), lists (`,`), and step values (`/`) as described [here](https://linuxize.com/post/cron-jobs-every-5-10-15-minutes/#crontab-syntax-and-operators).

This is my usage instructions:

```bash
function print_usage() {
  echo "Usage:  `basename $0` -a APPLICATION [-D DAY_OF_WEEK] [-M MONTH] [-d DAY_OF_MONTH] [-H HOUR] [-m MINUTE] [-u]"
  echo "Options:"
  echo " -a APPLICATION    EMR application (application:container)"
  echo " -D DAY_OF_WEEK    day of the week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)"
  echo " -M MONTH          month (1 - 12)"
  echo " -d DAY_OF_MONTH   day of the month (1 - 31)"
  echo " -H HOUR           hour (0 - 23)"
  echo " -m MINUTE         minute (0 - 59)"
  echo " -u                uninstall the CRON job(s) for the application"
  exit 0
}
```

And these are the current validations that I have in place:

```bash
if [[ ! $DAY_OF_WEEK =~ ^(0?[0-7]|\*)$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: DAY_OF_WEEK parameter must be a positive integer (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7) or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
if [[ ! $MONTH =~ ^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])|\*)$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: MONTH parameter must be a positive integer (1 - 12) or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
if [[ ! $DAY_OF_MONTH =~ ^((0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])|\*)$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: DAY_OF_MONTH parameter must be a positive integer (1 - 31) or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
if [[ ! $HOUR =~ ^((0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])|\*)$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: HOUR parameter must be a positive integer (0 - 23) or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
if [[ ! $MINUTE =~ ^((0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])|\*)$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: MINUTE parameter must be a positive integer (0 - 59) or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
```

I'm not really sure how to begin to support ranges, lists, and step values for the scheduling parameters. Right now, if you specify `15` for the minute parameter, it will run the script at minute 15 of the hour - but no way to specify every 15 minutes unless I support parameter values like `*/15`.

Comment: you seem to understand the basics of bash regex. While it might be possble to make one regex that would do all you want, I would  go with `||`ed tests or even `elif` blocks of code. I don't see any easy solution. ... Should you be spending time on such things?  .... Doesn't `crontab` reject bad records when you try to install them? I would spend some time experimenting with that and trapping those errors. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - I think that's a valid point. And no I am not good at regex, what I have here is from another question I asked here before. Is it better to not validate those scheduling parameters and let crontab fail if they are invalid? The problem I see there is I would like to halt all executions if my parameters are invalid before I even do anything at all. If I leave the validation to crontab, it may come later in the script and I would've already done some processing before then.

Comment: Is this for a production environment? If so, should users be making changes to the scheduling system (cron)? Get a safe cron acct and do a few quick tests on your system with deliberately bad data and see how cron responds. Also keep in mind that a Large Scale vendor's crontab (redHat and others) may respond differently that the crons include with more user-focused systems (Ubuntu, etc) `cron` validating users entries may not work on any system, so just do the quickest tests to help decide if you want to pursue that idea. Good luck

Comment: different cron implementations accept different values, and semantics of specific values can vary. so even if input validates against your code it may behave incorrectly when loaded in the specific cron or be rejected - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a tool to manipulate text. A shell is a tool to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and sequence calls to other tools. The mandatory POSIX (available on all Unix boxes) tool for general purpose text manipulation is awk. So, to manipulate text using shell, the right approach is to write an awk script to do the text manipulation and then the shell script is mostly just a call to awk to interpret the awk script.

You can read the awk output into bash scalar variables or arrays if necessary to use them later in your shell script IF you need to use shell for anything else but if you're just manipulating text then just do it all in awk.

Here's a start on how to expand ranges of numbers and strings:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

expand() {
    awk -v dowNums="$1" -v monthNums="$2" -v dowStrs="$3" -v monthStrs="$4" '
        BEGIN {
            printf "dowNums\t\"%s\"\t-> \"%s\"\n", dowNums, expandNums(dowNums,1,7)
            printf "monthNums\t\"%s\"\t-> \"%s\"\n", monthNums, expandNums(monthNums,1,12)
            printf "dowStrs\t\"%s\"\t-> \"%s\"\n", dowStrs, expandStrs(dowStrs,"Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun")
            printf "monthStrs\t\"%s\"\t-> \"%s\"\n", monthStrs, expandStrs(monthStrs,"Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec")
        }

        function expandNums(spec,minBeg,maxEnd, \
                                beg,end,range,i,list) {
            if ( spec == "" ) {
                return
            }

            if ( spec ~ /^[^*-]+$/ ) {
                beg = spec
                end = beg
            }
            else if ( spec == "*" ) {
                beg = minBeg
                end = maxEnd
            }
            else if ( split(spec,range,"-") == 2 ) {
                beg = range[1]
                end = range[2]
            }

            if ( ( beg+0 == beg ) &&
                 ( end+0 == end ) &&
                 ( beg <= end ) &&
                 ( (minBeg <= beg) && (beg <= maxEnd) ) &&
                 ( (minBeg <= end) && (end <= maxEnd) ) )
            {
                for ( i=beg; i<=end; i++ ) {
                    list = list i (i<end ? OFS : "")
                }
            }

            if ( list == "" ) {
                printf "Bad spec: \"%s\"\n", spec |"cat>&2"
            }

            return list
        }

        function expandStrs(spec,vals, \
                                idxs2vals,vals2idxs,minBeg,maxEnd,beg,end,range,i,list) {
            if ( spec == "" ) {
                return
            }

            minBeg = 1
            maxEnd = split(vals,idxs2vals," ")
            for ( i in idxs2vals) {
                vals2idxs[idxs2vals[i]] = i+0   # array indices are strings, we need numbers
            }

            if ( spec ~ /^[^*-]+$/ ) {
                beg = ( spec in vals2idxs ? vals2idxs[spec] : "" )
                end = beg
            }
            else if ( spec == "*" ) {
                beg = minBeg
                end = maxEnd
            }
            else if ( split(spec,range,"-") == 2 ) {
                beg = ( range[1] in vals2idxs ? vals2idxs[range[1]] : "" )
                end = ( range[2] in vals2idxs ? vals2idxs[range[2]] : "" )
            }

            if ( ( beg+0 == beg ) &&
                 ( end+0 == end ) &&
                 ( beg <= end ) &&
                 ( (minBeg <= beg) && (beg <= maxEnd) ) &&
                 ( (minBeg <= end) && (end <= maxEnd) ) )
            {
                for ( i=beg; i<=end; i++ ) {
                    list = list idxs2vals[i] (i<end ? OFS : "")
                }
            }

            if ( list == "" ) {
                printf "Bad spec: \"%s\"\n", spec |"cat>&2"
            }

            return list
        }
    '
}

echo "Varying day of week number specs"
expand '4'      ''      ''              ''
expand '3-6'    ''      ''              ''
expand '*'      ''      ''              ''

echo ""
echo "Varying month number specs"
expand ''       '4'     ''              ''
expand ''       '3-6'   ''              ''
expand ''       '*'     ''              ''

echo ""
echo "Varying day of week abbreviation specs"
expand ''       ''      'Tue'           ''
expand ''       ''      'Wed-Fri'       ''
expand ''       ''      '*'             ''

echo ""
echo "Varying month abbreviation specs"
expand ''       ''      ''              'Apr'
expand ''       ''      ''              'Mar-Jun'
expand ''       ''      ''              '*'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Varying day of week number specs
dowNums "4"     -> "4"
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       ""      -> ""
dowNums "3-6"   -> "3 4 5 6"
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       ""      -> ""
dowNums "*"     -> "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       ""      -> ""

Varying month number specs
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       "4"     -> "4"
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       ""      -> ""
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       "3-6"   -> "3 4 5 6"
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       ""      -> ""
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       "*"     -> "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12"
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       ""      -> ""

Varying day of week abbreviation specs
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs "Tue"   -> "Tue"
monthStrs       ""      -> ""
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs "Wed-Fri"       -> "Wed Thu Fri"
monthStrs       ""      -> ""
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs "*"     -> "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
monthStrs       ""      -> ""

Varying month abbreviation specs
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       "Apr"   -> "Apr"
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       "Mar-Jun"       -> "Mar Apr May Jun"
dowNums ""      -> ""
monthNums       ""      -> ""
dowStrs ""      -> ""
monthStrs       "*"     -> "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"
```